# Dot product inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm looking for a pair of vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, with $x , y > 0$ (the inequality holds element-wise), such that
$$
(a - \boldsymbol{1}_n)^\top x > \boldsymbol{1}_m^\top y, 
$$
where $\boldsymbol{1}_p$ is the $p$-dimensional vector with all the elements equal to $1$, while $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is some parameter. Any condition on $a$ that could guarantee the existence of such pair $x,y$? A pointer to some literature on this kind of inequalities would be much appreciated.

Comment: Such a pair exists if and only if $a$ has at least one entry bigger than $1$ since then you can pump the left hand side to plus infinity using that coordinate.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thank you for answering. What do you mean with "pump the LHS"? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Sorry. I mean you can make LHS as big as you want if only at least one coordinate of $a-1$ is positive. You just put a sufficiently large value in $x$ at that coordinate.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek OK, now it makes much more sense to me. Thank you.